# C++/Qt: How to create a busyloop which you can put on pause?

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a better answer to this question than creating a spinlock-like structure with a global boolean flag which is checked in the loop?

```cpp
bool isRunning = true;

void busyLoop()
{
    for (;;) {
        if (!isRunning)
            continue;
        // ...
    }
}

int main()
{
    // ...
    QPushButton *startBusyLoopBtn = new QPushButton("start busy loop");
    QObject::connect(startBusyLoopBtn, QPushButton::clicked, [](){ busyLoop(); });
    
    QPushButton *startPauseBtn = new QPushButton("start/pause");
    QObject::connect(startPauseBtn, QPushButton::clicked, [](){ isRunning = !isRunning; });
    // ...
}
```

To begin with, we waste the CPU time while checking the flag. Secondly, we need two separate buttons for this scheme to work. How can we use Qt's slot-signal mechanism for a simpler solution?

Comment: Take a look at `std::condition_variable`. I don't know if Qt has it's own implementation of it. You can create start/pause/stop mechanism with it, instead of checking a variable in a loop this will put the thread to sleep until it is notified to continue.

Comment: You will need to check somehow.  I don't think it's appropriate to just run the busy loop as a slot, since the event will be processed by the event queue and block all subsequent event processing.  You're better off doing this as a worker thread, which I agree could sit and wait for a condition variable to be signalled before activating (and then test a flag with appropriate synchronization to shut down).  Or you could spawn and terminate the thread in response to these buttons -- kinda dangerous though.  To reduce "load" from flag testing, do it less often by batching your busy sections.

Comment: If your intention is to do some work in the "buysy loop", which can be paused and resumed, and do this in the main thread yet still have GUI responsive, you should add `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` to your busy loop and call it frequently enough. Otherwise your code will not work because the main thread will become blocked by the "busy loop". This is however not an ideal solution. You should learn more about multithreading in Qt. But it is very advanced topic.

Comment: @V.K. Yes, I do have it in my actual code.

Comment: @kenticent read my answer carefully, you have everything you need there. If you need help with it don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `std::condition_variable`:

```
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable cv_start_stop;

    std::thread thr([&](){
        /**
         * this thread will notify and unpause the main loop 3 seconds later
         */
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(3000));
        cv_start_stop.notify_all();
    });

    bool paused = true;
    while (true)
    {
        if (paused)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
            cv_start_stop.wait(lock); // this will lock the thread until notified.
            std::cout << "thread unpaused\n";
            paused = false;
        }
        std::cout << "loop goes on until paused\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
```

This will not brutally check for a flag to continue, instead, it will put thread to sleep until notified.

You will simply make `paused = true;` to pause and `cv_start_stop.notify_one();` or `cv_start_stop.notify_all();` to unpause.